# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, xhtml

en el momento se me presento un error que no he podido resolver en diferentes foros.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for >JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   'catch' without 'try'
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   'finally' without 'try'
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   reached end of file while parsing

Necesito ayuda!!!

```
==============================content================================-->
            <!--
            RECUPERAMOS LOS DATOS A MODIFICAR
            -->
            <%           
               String ofi = request.getParameter( "ofi" );
               String micro = request.getParameter("micro");
               String idP = request.getParameter("idP");
               String nomP = request.getParameter( "nomP" );
               String dirP = request.getParameter("dirP");
               String codP = request.getParameter("codP");
            %>
        <section id="content"><div class="ic"></div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                                            <article class="grid_8" >
                            <div class="indent-top indent-left">
                                                       <br/>
                                                        <h3>EDITAR PUNTO</h3>
                                                            <form id="form-agregar" method="post" name="form1" action="editarPunto">                    
                                                                <fieldset>
                                                                      <legend align="right" >Datos Punto a Editar</legend>
                                                                            <label><span class="text-form2">Oficina:</span>
                                                                             <select name="txtOficina" onchange="">
                                                                                <%                                                                             
                                                                                 // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request 
                                                                                    Servicios s = new Servicios( );
                                                                                    ResultSet droplst = s.Oficinas( 0, "" );
                                                                                    int oficina ;
                                                                                    if(droplst != null){                                                                                    
                                                                                        while( droplst.next( ) )
                                                                                        { 
                                                                                             if(droplst.getString( 2 ).equals(ofi)){
                                                                                                out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"' selected>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                                out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                                                                                            }                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }  
                                                                                %>                                                                           
                                                                            </select></label> 
                                                                            <label><span class="text-form2">Micro-Zona:</span>
                                                                                <select name="txtMZ" onchange="">
                                                                                <%  
                                                                                    String MZ = "1";//microzonas en Oficina
                                                                                    ResultSet droplst2 = s.consultarMicroZona(0, MZ ,"" );

                                                                                    if(droplst2 != null){                                                                                    
                                                                                        while( droplst2.next( ) )
                                                                                        {      
                                                                                            if(droplst.getString( 2 ).equals(micro)){
                                                                                                out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"' selected>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                            out.println("<option value='"+ droplst2.getInt( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst2.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");                                                                                        
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }  
                                                                                %>                                                                           
                                                                            </select></label>                                                                       
                                                                             <label><span class="text-form2">Id del Punto:</span><input name="txtIdP" type="text"  type="text"  value="<%out.println(idP);%>" readonly="readonly"/></label>
                                                                            <label><span class="text-form2">Nombre del Punto:</span><input name="txtNomP" type="text"  type="text"  value="<%out.println(nomP);%>" required="required"/></label>
                                                                            <label><span class="text-form2">Direccion del Punto:</span><input name="txtDrP" type="text"  type="text"  value="<%out.println(dirP);%>" required="required"/></label>
                                                                            <label><span class="text-form2">C&oacute;digo del Punto:</span><input name="txtCodP" type="text"  type="text"  value="<%out.println(codP);%>" required="required"/></label>
                                                                    </fieldset> 
                                                                    <br/>    
                                                                    <button type="submit">AGREGAR</button>
                                                                    <button type="reset">CANCELAR</button>
                                                            </form>   

                            </div>
                        </article>
                                            <article class="grid_4">
                            <div class="indent-top indent-left">
                                <div class="wrapper margin-bot">
                                                                <div class="box-1">
                                                                <strong class="number img-atras" onclick="location = 'inicio.jsp'"></strong>
                                                                <p class="text-3">VOLVER AL MENU</p>
                                                                </div>
                                </div>     
                            </div>
                        </article>
                                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--
```

Hola;  Sigo con el mismo problema; Pero para poder avanzar omiti esta parte unos dias sin embargo se me presento el mismo inconveniente...

Me fije que el problema se presenta en la comparacion :

```
if(droplst2 != null){                                                                                    
                                                                                    while( droplst2.next( ) )
                                                                                    {      
                                                                                        if(droplst.getString( 2 ).equals(micro)){
                                                                                            out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"' selected>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                        out.println("<option value='"+ droplst2.getInt( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst2.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");                                                                                        
                                                                                    }}
```

El problema con esto es que necesito hacer la comparación para que el dato anteriormente seleccionado salga  por defecto. tengo 2 drop drow list en la pagina si elimino 1 de esas dos comparaciones no me salta la excepción...

Alguna idea?

Como siempre muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que estás intentando hacer? ¿Cuál es la línea 21 de prueba.jsp? Por el mensaje de error, parece que estás usando una versión obsoleta, ¿has probado con una más moderna?

Comment: Modifique  el error que se presenta; @AlvaroMontoro  lo que intento  en esta pagina es recuperar los valores presentes en  una tabla en una pagina.   paso los valores por <a editarpunto.jsp?ofi='preuba'&micro=prueba2.....> y funciona con varias paginas , pero esta me salta el error .... a que se debe.

Comment: El error que te muestra ahora es que hay un `catch` sin un `try`. El código que compartes no tiene ningún `catch`, por lo que no parece ser el código que da error.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la URL  ES: /Seapto/editarPunto.jsp?ofi=Bodega%20&micro=microzona2&idP=1%20&nomP=prueba%20&dirP=prueba%20&codP=123

Comment: Modifique la publicación y agregue  la pagina que hace el llamado ... desde búsqueda a edición.

Gracias!

Comment: Al comentario anterior me remito: el error que recibes es que hay un `catch` sin un `try`. El código que compartes no tiene ni `try`, `catch` ni `finally`, por lo que no es el código que te da el error.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro puedo contactarte? y enviarte el proyecto ...  no  tengo ningún try ni catch en todo mi proyecto ...

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer en estos casos es remover todo el scriptlet e ir agregándolo de a pocos nuevamente para poder detectar el error. Adicionalmente, sería bueno trabajar para que tus JSPs no tengan scriptlets en absoluto.

Comment: @luiggiMendoza ... increíblemente me toco implementar tu sugerencia... encontré el error ... pero sigo sin entender por que se presenta ...

Comment: Debe ser por una malformación del código. El scriptlet es muy difícil de mantener, y por experiencia sé que esa "técnica" funciona a pesar de ser tediosa. Lo mejor es modificar el código para no usar scriptlets en absoluto.

Answer (score 1):

Hola gente después de probar  muchas soluciones la solución era utilizar las etiquetas

```
//<![CDATA[// ... Codigo .... ]]>
```

Así cuando se lea en xml no se separa las sentencias scriptlets.

El código jsp quedo así :

```
int num = 0;
 // Se instancia los recursos del modelo y se da respuesta al request 
    Servicios s = new Servicios( );
    ResultSet droplst = s.Ciudad( num , "" );                                                                                
    //<![CDATA[
    if(droplst != null){                                                                                    
        while( droplst.next( ) )                                                                                          
        {    
             if (droplst.getString( 2 ).equals(ciuU)){
             //if((ciuU == null && droplst.getString( 2 ) == null) || ciuU.equalsIgnoreCase(droplst.getString( 2 ))){//Por defecto
                out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"' selected>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
            }else{
                  out.println("<option value='"+ droplst.getInt( 1 ) +"'>"+ droplst.getString( 2 ) +"</option>");
            } 
               
        }
    }
    //  ]]>
    droplst.close();
```